# Cannot find the appropriate linux header

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, header-files, raspberry-pi2

DISCLAIMER: Maybe this type of question is not appropriate for Stackoevrflow. If that is the case, I apologize. I would also be glad to hear what is the proper case to ask :)

---

I have the following OS running in my Raspberry Pi 2:

```
uname -r
4.14.56-v7+
```

However, when I try to install some drivers (via `make` or via `dkms install`), I get an error because I do not have the kernel headers. For example:

```
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 4.14.56-v7+ cannot be found at
/lib/modules/4.14.56-v7+/build or /lib/modules/4.14.56-v7+/source.
```

I have been looking for hours, but I am completly unable of finding the header files anywhere. Of course, I have tried `sudo apt-get install linux-headers`, but there is no candidate: `E: Package 'linux-headers' has no installation candidate`.

Finally, it is worth mentioning that I have the headers for a previous kernel version:

```
ll /usr/src
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4.0K Jul 26 18:23 linux-headers-4.14.52+/
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4.0K Jul 26 18:23 linux-headers-4.14.52-v7+/
```

Does anybody have an idea as to how to fix this issue? I am desesperate by now.

Comment: "I would also be glad to hear what is the proper case to ask :)" - You use tag [tag:raspberry-pi], and it suggests you to ask *non-programming* questions on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ as non-programming question about raspberry.

Comment: I agree, the question does not belong here. Thank you for letting me know, @Tsyvarev!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue downgrading to 4.14.52

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

If that doesn't work , try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: Thanks, but these commands do not work for 4.14.57. I solved the issue downgrading to 4.14.52!